# Ember.js using each, get count

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using Ember.js with handlebars, and looping through results like:

```
{{#each transaction in transactions }}
    <p>Transaction: {{ transaction.name }}</p>
{{else}}
    <p>No results...</p>
```

How can I look at the total count of `transactions` and if greater than 10, add a simple load more:

```
<p><a {{action loadMoreResults}}>Load more transactions...</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom handlebar helper, something like `if_gt`

```
{{#if_gt transactions.length compare="10"}}
       <p><a {{action loadMoreResults}}>Load more transactions...</a></p>
{{/if_gt}}
```

And your Helper will be defined something like this

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_gt', function(context, options) {
  if (context > options.hash.compare)
      return options.fn(this);
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

In that case you can try this.. just move the element to outside the `loop`

```
{{#if something}}
     {{#each transaction in transactions }}
         <p>Transaction: {{ transaction.name }}</p>
     {{/each}}
{{else}}
    <p>No results...</p> 
{{/if}}

{{#if_gt total_transactions compare="10"}}
    <p>Load more...</p>
{{/if_gt}}
```

Comment: in tandem with ember.js this is a bad practice tough, keep your templates clean and free of logic that belongs elsewhere :)

Comment: So I have: https://gist.github.com/nodesocket/ca2e1b5e8ae52f44dd10 but the problem is I am seeing `Load more...` for each row. How can I extend my `if` check to say only do this if check on the last `transaction`.

Comment: @Sushanth-- Yeah, I think there is a bug in `handlebars helpers`, see my issue: https://github.com/danharper/Handlebars-Helpers/issues/9

Comment: Where did you declare the Handle bar helper.. you can always put a break point and check what is happening\

Comment: I believe handler bar helper is being loaded, or else I would get `Uncaught Error:  Handlebars error: Could not find property 'if_gt'. Right?

Comment: It is better to just use `{{#if showLoadMore}}` and define `showLoadMore` as a computed property in a controller.

Comment: @LukeMelia Yeah I could do that, but feel like I am super close using handlebars.

Comment: If you really want to go the handlebars helper route (and I strongly recommend against it for this!), you will want to use `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` so that the helper re-renders when the conditional changes.